# ALTER COLUMN datatype with indexed one

Tags: sql, types, indexing, alter

Is there a way I can change a column data type without dropping the index.

With disabling option it can't `'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ' + @tablename + ' DISABLE '`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logically speaking this should not be possible.
You are changing the underlying data type, so reindexing has to happen.

So if you have a `number` column and you change it `varchar` then database will have to rearrange things which implies index will have to be recreated.